# Where is the hard drive in a Mac Book Pro 15" (early 2011)?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

This morning I am hearing an occasional periodic quiet clicking type noise from my macbook, from roughly the lower right quadrant, underneath the arrow keys.  I have no CD/DVD in the optical drive.   The noise repeats 5 to 10 times and then quits for a while, and it repeats at a regular rate of less than a second.

My question is: is that where my hard drive is?  If not, what is in that spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [iFixit's teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+Teardown/4990/1), the hard drive is located in the lower right corner. The lower left is pretty much just the battery, which doesn't really have any mechanical parts that could make a clicking sort of noise.

Perhaps listen a little closer and see if you can isolate the noise better. I would also *strongly* recommend making regular backups if you don't already, as a clicking hard drive is not a good sound, if that is where it's coming from.